# Git lab pipeline Android project

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab

I create an android project in git lab. I'm trying to use pipelines .

The build failed with message

`Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.`

How can I accept this licences automatically?
Adding `--no-ui --all` is not enough (I have already tried to add them!).

I tried all the soluctions presented [here](you need to accept the license agreements and complete) with no success.

Does someone actually managed to make git lab pipelines works for android?

Below my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "24"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "25.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "25.0.3"

before_script:
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
  - unzip android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

Comment: By now Gitlab has a CI template for Android, which is described in detail in this post: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/ It still requires downloading and installing SDK tools on the fly each time it runs, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `sdkmanager` cli can be used to update sdks/ accept licenses.
To accept all licenses you can run

`echo y | tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: `sdkmanager` command is not included in the tools zip you must download the entire sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I finnally resolve the problem using `sdkmanager` but I had to download the `sdk` `zip` instead of the `tools` `zip` like the code in my original question.

This is the final code I copied from [Nick Petrovsky post](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1956) on gitlab issue tracker

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "24"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "25.0.3"
 # ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "25.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS_REV: "3859397"  # "26.0.1"

before_script:
  - mkdir $HOME/.android # For sdkmanager configs
  - echo 'count=0' > $HOME/.android/repositories.cfg # Avoid warning
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS_REV}.zip
  - mkdir $PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - unzip -qq android-sdk.zip -d $PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle # Remove if you don't need NDK
  - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update 
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'tools'
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'platform-tools'
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'build-tools;'$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'platforms;android-'$ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'extras;android;m2repository'
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'extras;google;google_play_services'
  - echo y | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'extras;google;m2repository'
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used [this gitlab-ci-android docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jerbob92/gitlab-ci-android/)

It is faster and cause much less problems:

```
before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - mkdir -p $GRADLE_USER_HOME
    - chmod +x ./gradlew

cache:
  paths:
     - .gradle/wrapper
     - .gradle/caches

build:
  stage: build
  script:
     - ./gradlew assemble

test:
  stage: test
  script:
     - ./gradlew check
```

Comment: Fails for me with `Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.` And it seems to lack `sdkmanager` so I can’t accept them.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a CI image for Android, which can be found at https://gitlab.com/mvglasow/android-gitlab-ci.

It is based on what is described at https://about.gitlab.com/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/, but it has all the Android tools in the image already so you don’t have to install them again for every CI run. Compared to the instructions, the image saves you about 30 seconds per pipeline.